# How to run method untill app is closed

Tags: javascript, cordova, setinterval

I have one method like this

```
function one(){
   //ajax call for server posting 
}
```

on page 1. This method is called every 5th minute until app is closed. This is done by using *setInterval* like this

```
setInterval( one, 50000 );
```

It works nicely until we move to page 2 where it isn't called even once. How can I get it to work on page 2 too.

Answer (score 0):

So declare the function *one* and set the interval on the *index.html* to not bind it to the certain page? There seems to be no limitation in your question that would not allow this to be done.